# Remove duplicates from listview depending on first column value

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is remove duplicate rows in a listView but only if the 1st column is duplicated for example:

**NAME / AGE / JOB**

John / 24  / Engineer

Tom  / 32  / Golfer

John / 55  / Scientist

The name John is in there twice, i would just prefer to have it once, and delete all other rows, this is the basic code i have so far is:

```
public void RemoveDuplicates() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listViewTwitter.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (listViewTwitter.Items[i].Tag == listViewTwitter.Items[i + 1].Tag)
        {
            listViewTwitter.Items[i + 1].Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot think of the best way to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is an example which I wrote for you.

To make my exmaple better, First I created a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

Then I declared a list of objects of `Person` class.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { Age = 24 , Job = "Engineer", Name = "John" },
        new Person() { Age = 32, Job = "Golfer", Name = "Tom " },
        new Person() { Age = 55, Job = "Scientist",Name = "John" },
    };


    foreach (var person in list)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(person.Name);
        item.Tag = person;

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then I remove all dupplicates by pressing a button, with two `for-loop`

```
private void btnRemoveDupplicates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=0;i<listView1.Items.Count;i++)
    {

        var person = (Person)listView1.Items[i].Tag;
        for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if(
                ((Person)listView1.Items[j].Tag).Name == person.Name && 
                listView1.Items[i].Index != listView1.Items[j].Index)
            {                        
                listView1.Items[j].Remove();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```